# Transferring money: effective person-to-person transfer mechanisms: ACH, Fednow,wire, something else?

Tags: united-states, banking, transfer, ach

I'm curious what mechanisms exist to transfer "largish" amounts of money from one individual to another in the US.

Sending a check seems archaic and the last one I sent was lost in the mail.

Zelle, Venmo, Paypal, cashapp and the like are limited to small amounts. Paypal says they will do tranfers up to 10k, but I've never had it work above 1-2k. These services are also unwieldy in that you have to get the other person to sign up to the service. (Ideally it would be possible to send money just given a bank account and routing number.)

Wise has a very nice interface to transfer money using ACH or wire transfers, but first you have to wire the money to Wise, which sort of defeats the purpose.

Melio will do ACH transfers for free and would be great, but they don't allow person-to-person transfers. (Or person to business.)

Wire transfers work but have an absurdly large overhead for a modern banking system.

Fednow has started to roll out and hopefully will provide this sort of capability, but I don't know of any bank/financial institution providing Fednow transfers right now.

Are there US banks that provide ACH transfers to unlinked accounts?

Does anyone have suggestions on how to transfer money in the US?

Comment: *Wire transfers work but have an absurdly large overhead for a modern banking system.* - citation needed. What do you mean by "overhead"? In general, service recommendation requests don't age very well. FedNow adoption will increase in the future and the ACH transfers will (hopefully) disappear into the abyss as they should have years ago.

Comment: Most banks charge the sender $20 to $50 to send a wire.  Receiving banks often charge the recipient $15 to $40 to receive a wire.  It shouldn't cost that much to transfer money in an electronic banking system.

Comment: It shouldn't, but in the US there's no regulation that forbids banks from charging whatever they want. If you need to use this service - you'll pay. Why shouldn't they charge?

Comment: I don't want to get into a debate about free-market economics.   I have no issue with banks charging whatever they want to transfer funds.  But it seems that more effective mechanisms than wire transfers should  exist for the US.  After you've lived with SEPA in the EU, it's hard to deal with the US inefficiencies.

Comment: The problem with the US having been on the leading edge in many technologies is that we have a huge pile of early investment in infrastructure that mostly works and would cost a huge amount to upgrade. Eventually it gets improved, but only when there's sufficient market advantage in doing so. Meanwhile, yes, we have some legacy inefficiencies. You can fret, or you can cope, depending on which saw you have available.

Comment: @hillbump most US residents have never lived outside their own State, let alone with SEPA in the EU. Sure, anyone with a couple of brain cells understands how ridiculous the US banking system is, but most Americans... well... don't.

Comment: @keshlam there's absolutely no extra scrutiny in extra transfers over $10K specifically, and on the contrary - breaking transactions deliberately to avoid scrutiny would be an actual crime even if the money itself is kosher.

Comment: Apologies for misremembering. And my point wasn't that one should break up transactions, just that the problem being cited doesn't affect most normal transactions. (Ask me some time about the day I spent running around to many different credit unions to get around the limitations on "shared branch" withdrawals.)

Comment: @hillbump The banks would still charge $50 to use the efficient services, and pocket the difference.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth: in my experience the US is still stuck in the financial stone age and paper checks are indeed the best option to move around large sums of money domestically.

Every time I had to do this in the last few years (account moves, retirement rollover, real estate transaction) I looked at all available options and paper check always came in at the best. The amount of rigmarole that the banks put up to overcomplicate electronic transactions is mind-boggling (daily limits, monthly limits, pull vs push limits, account linking, a large variety of sizable fees, etc.) For some strange reasons none of those apply to paper checks. Probably that's all done intentionally to protect their fee revenue.

That's in stark contrast with Europe where you can move money around electronically pretty much instantaneously and for free. I've never run into a cap or limit in Europe (but that's all been less than $1M). Ironically moving a large sum of money between my European and US Wise accounts is a lot faster (and cheaper) than moving money domestically in the US.

Comment: I've recently came into a situation where a US bank plainly refused to execute my wire transfer request (between my own accounts) and went even further as to block my funds for a week until I was able to convince their security person that yes, I am in fact putting a down payment on the house, not that it's their business. The US banks are ridiculous, but it's an oligopoly with zero governmental oversight, so you get what you get.

Comment: If you're worried about losing the check, is it possible to walk up to the bank in person and non-electronically tell them to send the money?